# Un-hide and focus an element in a Lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I want to show an input element that is hidden, and focus it.

Component code:

```
<aura:component >
    <div>
        <input aura:id="input" class="hidden"/>
        <button onclick="{!c.toggleAndFocus}">Toggle and focus!</button>
        <button onclick="{!c.focus}">Focus!</button>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    toggleAndFocus : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var input = cmp.find("input");
        $A.util.toggleClass(input, "hidden");
        input.getElement().focus();
    },

    focus : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var input = cmp.find("input").getElement().focus();
    }
})
```

And the `hidden` CSS class just applies `display: none`.

Pressing the "Toggle and focus!" button toggles the visibility of the input as expected. However, it doesn't focus the input after showing it. Pressing the "Focus!" button when the input is shown focusses the input as expected.

How can I make this "Toggle and focus!" button focus the input after showing it?

Comment: Could you try setting a timeout before the focus? I think I encountered something similar and setting a timeout did the trick in focusing.

Comment: I thought about this, and just tried it. It does work, I was just hoping there was a cleaner way - but might be stuck with it

Comment: @nicstella it has to do with the rendering life cycle of Aura. The elements are not actually updated until the function returns, so you need a callback afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If your focus() function works, why don't you call it in your toggleAndFocus function?

Just move your focus() function to your helper

e.g.:

Controller:

```
toggleAndFocus : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var input = cmp.find("input");
    $A.util.toggleClass(input, "hidden");
    helper.focus(cmp);
}
```

Helper:

```
focus : function(cmp) {
    var input = cmp.find("input").getElement().focus();
}
```

If you want to call your focus function from a component handler, you need a controller function that passed through to the helper.

E.g.

Controller:

```
focus: function(cmp, event, helper){
    helper.focus(cmp)
}
```

Comment: It works when the element is already visible, not after toggling it to visible. Sounds like timeouts are the only way to do this, see the comments on the question if interested