# Blur everything on init

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-design-system

Loading a lightning component automatically focuses the first input element.

Lightning won't let me manipulate the DOM so this [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520650/how-do-you-clear-the-focus-in-javascript) solution won't work `document.activeElement.blur()`.

[This Solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155575/un-hide-and-focus-an-element-in-a-lightning-component) is too much, I don't want to pass in all the elements, is there anything to just "blur all"? Or even anything that let's me prevent focusing?